# Chamar função JS pelo Select

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho uma função em JS e pretendo executá-la quando mudar o select, eu chamo assim:

```js
$("#table1 .td_select select").on("click select", function(){
    calcSub($(this).closest("tr"));
    calcTotal();
});
```

```html
<div class="table1">
    <td class="td_select">   
     <select name="id_lub" id="id_lub" class="btn-block">
      <option value="">Nenhum</option>
            ...
  </select>
    </td>
</div>
```

Se eu mudar o *option* do *select* a função não é executada, porém se eu clicar em cima do *select* ele executa a função.
Acredito que estou chamando a função de forma errada ai em cima no JS. Seguindo a mesma estrutura, qual o jeito certo de inserir os dados entre $()?

Comment: Você poderia uasr o change assim:
 $(document).on('change', '#table1 .td_select select', function(){ /*code here*/ });

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para chamar uma função ao mudar o select você pode usar o [onchange](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp) que vai disparar a chamada sempre que selecionar outra opção

```js
function mudarSelect(valor){
  console.log(valor);
}
```

```html
<select onchange="mudarSelect(this.value)">
    <option value="valorA">Valor A</option>
    <option value="valorB">Valor B</option>
    <option value="valorC">Valor C</option>
</select>
```

em seu código, usando o JQuery, você está usando o seletor de  maneira errada. Seu código corrigido ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
$("#id_lub").on("change", function(){ //usando o id do select
    calcSub($(this).closest("tr"));
    calcTotal();
});

<div class="table1">
    <td class="td_select">          
        <select name="id_lub" id="id_lub" class="btn-block">
            <option value="">Nenhum</option>
            ...
        </select>
    </td>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

De acordo com a documentação do Jquery você pode fazer assim `$(seletor).change(function() { logica da função }`, tente usar assim ao envez de `.on('change')`.
E de preferencia para seletores com `id` igual fiz no exemplo abaixo:

```js
$("#id_lub").change(function() {
   console.log('x');
})
```

```html
    <script
   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
   integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
   crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>


        <div class="table1">
           <td class="td_select">   
           <select name="id_lub" id="id_lub" class="btn-block">
            <option value="">Nenhum</option>
                <option value="">Nenhum1</option>
                <option value="">Nenhum2</option>
                ...
      </select>
           </td>
        </div>
```